How to obtain emulator binary in latest rocket-chip using mill and chisel 5.0.0?
I've setup Chisel 5.0.0 and firtool as I explained in this other question. I also installed successfully mill and rocket-tools as instructed here and here.
This prepared the stage for getting the latest rocket-chip and I would like to get it going in Chisel 5.0.0. Having checked out the code and installed dependencies, it should be ready for running make verilog, as instructed from here.
This does finish successfully (as in - there are no errors reported):
[build.sc] [48/52] compile 
[info] compiling 4 Scala sources to /home/user/rocket-chip/out/mill-build/compile.dest/classes ...
[warn] /home/user/rocket-chip/build.sc:205:155: method any2stringadd in object Predef is deprecated (since 2.13.0): Implicit injection of + is deprecated. Convert to String to call +
[warn]          |"$${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DVERILATOR -DTEST_HARNESS=VTestHarness -include VTestHarness.h -include verilator.h -include ${generator.elaborate().path / config + ".plusArgs"}")
[warn]                                                                                                                                                           ^
[warn] one warning found
[info] done compiling
[40/168] macros.compile 
[info] compiling 1 Scala source to /home/user/rocket-chip/out/macros/compile.dest/classes ...
[info] done compiling
[76/168] hardfloat[5.0.0].compile 
[info] compiling 20 Scala sources to /home/user/rocket-chip/out/hardfloat/5.0.0/compile.dest/classes ...
[warn] 535 feature warnings; re-run with -feature for details
[warn] one warning found
[info] done compiling
[107/168] cde.compile 
[info] compiling 1 Scala source to /home/user/rocket-chip/out/cde/compile.dest/classes ...
[info] done compiling
[140/168] rocketchip[5.0.0].compile 
[info] compiling 314 Scala sources to /home/user/rocket-chip/out/rocketchip/5.0.0/compile.dest/classes ...
[warn] 9 deprecations
[warn] 67 deprecations (since 2.13.0)
[warn] 1 deprecation (since 2.13.7)
[warn] 48 deprecations (since CDE 0.1)
[warn] 1 deprecation (since Chisel 3.5)
[warn] 42 deprecations (since Chisel 3.6)
[warn] 168 deprecations in total; re-run with -deprecation for details
[warn] 2617 feature warnings; re-run with -feature for details
[warn] 8 warnings found
[info] done compiling
[165/168] emulator[freechips.rocketchip.system.TestHarness,freechips.rocketchip.system.DefaultConfig].generator.elaborate 
<stdin>:69.27-72.5: Warning (simple_bus_reg): /soc/external-interrupts: missing or empty reg/ranges property
<stdin>:94.28-99.5: Warning (simple_bus_reg): /soc/subsystem_pbus_clock: missing or empty reg/ranges property
<stdin>:36.29-40.6: Warning (interrupt_provider): /cpus/cpu@0/interrupt-controller: Missing #address-cells in interrupt provider
[168/168] emulator[freechips.rocketchip.system.TestHarness,freechips.rocketchip.system.DefaultConfig].mfccompiler.compile 
user@8ab9b477893d:~/rocket-chip$ 


but, actually, not really, as I don't see the emulator binary! There pops up a directory called out, and there is out/emulator but there are no binaries anywhere, nor is there a verilog file to be found.
So, please, in the latest version of rocket-chip (commit: dbcb06a is latest on August 15th, 2024) how to:

emit verilog file?
get emulator binary?
run asm/benchmark tests?
generate waveform?

